# html scrape in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

In .net what is the best way to scrape HTML web pages.

Is there something open source that runs on .net framework 2 and and put all the html into objects. I have read about "HTML Agility Pack" but is there any think else?

Comment: Why did you tag this with [tag:c#] *and* [tag:vb.net]?

Comment: Are you trying to scape pages, or process pages? Do you need to look at the contextual information from the DOM or just Spider to duplicate?

Comment: I want the vb.net  to open the page and look at the html the take what it needs. I thought .net as it has more power than javscript and the sites wont be on my server

Comment: What are you looking to extract from the HTML you get back?

Comment: http://developer.mindtouch.com/SgmlReader

Comment: I want html ids on text boxes and and images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think HtmlAgilityPack is but you can also use

1. [Fizzler](http://code.google.com/p/fizzler/) : css selector engine for C#
2. [SgmlReader](http://developer.mindtouch.com/SgmlReader) : Convert html to valid xml
3. [SharpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/sharp-query/) : Alternative of fizzler

Answer (score 1):

You might use Tidy.net, which is a c# wrapper for the Tidy Library to convert HTML in XHTML available here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/tidynet/ so you could get valid XML and process it as such.

I'd make it this way:

```
        // don't forget to import TidyNet and System.Xml.Linq

        var t = new Tidy();
        TidyMessageCollection messages = new TidyMessageCollection();
        t.Options.Xhtml = true;

        //extra options if you plan to edit the result by hand
        t.Options.IndentContent = true;
        t.Options.SmartIndent = true;
        t.Options.DropEmptyParas = true;
        t.Options.DropFontTags = true;
        t.Options.BreakBeforeBR = true;




        string sInput = "your html code goes here";
        var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sInput);

        StringBuilder sbOutput = new StringBuilder();

        var msIn = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        var msOut = new MemoryStream();

        t.Parse(msIn, msOut, messages);
        var bytesOut = msOut.ToArray();
        string sOut = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesOut);

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(sOut);

        //process XML as you like
```

Otherwise, HTML Agility pack is ok.